# Does non-existence of surjection imply the existence of injection?

Tags: set-theory

I'm reading the definition of *cardinality strictly less than* in set theory and wondering if there's no surjection from $A$ to $B$, then can we conclude that there exists an injection from $A$ to $B$?

If $A$ and $B$ are finite then I can see that it's true. However, for infinite cases, I can't find some trivial counter-example.

Comment: This is true assuming the axiom of choice (since then you can well-order $A$ and $B$). Otherwise I think it's false but I'm not familiar with counterexamples.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan so the conclusion is true even if $A$ and $B$ are infinite assuming the axiom of choice. Do you have any proof for that?

Comment: It's a straightforward exercise. With the axiom of choice you can replace $A$ and $B$ with two ordinals WLOG. Now you show that the class of ordinals is itself totally ordered in the sense that for any two ordinals there must exist an injection from one to the other (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals).

Comment: "If $A$ and $B$ are finite then I can see that it's true." What if $B=\varnothing$ and $A\ne\varnothing$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks, it's beyond my knowledge (at the moment). But I'll definitely take a look at that soon.

Comment: @user14111, It's vacuously true also, since the empty function from the $\varnothing$ to $B$ is one-to-one function for any set $B$.

Comment: Huh? If $B=\varnothing$ and $A\ne\varnothing$, are you saying there is an injection from $A$ to $B$, or are you saying there is a surjection from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: @user14111, Ahh I mistook $A=\varnothing$ for $A\neq \varnothing$. if  $A\neq \varnothing\wedge B=\varnothing$ then $^{A}B=\ ^{A}\varnothing=\varnothing$ is surjective right?

Comment: @user14111, I was so dumb yesterday, $\varnothing$ means no functions so neither surjection nor injection exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method Qiaochu Yuan mentioned in the comments (using choice to biject with ordinals) works well and I very much encourage you to have a look at that method as well, because the idea of bijecting with ordinals often helps when thinking about this kind of thing. In this answer I will present a direct proof using [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma), an equivalent formulation of the axiom of choice.

We let $P$ be the set of partial injections from $A$ to $B$. That is:
$$
P = \{ f: A' \to B \; \mid \; A' \subseteq A \text{ and } f \text{ is injective}\}.
$$
We order $P$ by extension, that is $f \leq g$ if $\operatorname{dom}(f) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(g)$ and $g|_{\operatorname{dom}(f)} = f$, this makes $P$ into a partial order. Note that $P$ is nonempty, as it contains the empty function $\emptyset \to B$, which is always injective (vacuously). For any chain $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ in $P$ we have an upper bound $\bigcup_{i \in I} f_i$ (it is a straightforward check that this is in fact an injection from a subset of $A$ to $B$ again).

We can thus apply Zorn's lemma to $P$ to find a maximal element $f: A' \to B$. By construction $f$ is an injection. We will show that $A' = A$. Suppose not, so $A - A'$ is nonempty. Let $a \in A - A'$. As there are no surjections from $A$ to $B$ there are definitely no surjections from $A'$ to $B$, so $f$ cannot be a surjection. We thus find $b \in B$ that is not in the image of $f$. We can now extend $f$ to $g: A' \cup \{a\} \to B$ by setting $g(a) = b$. By construction $g$ is injective and so $g \in P$. We also have $f < g$, contradicting maximality of $f$. So we must have had $A' = A$ in the first place, and we conclude that $f: A \to B$ is the required injection.